# How to parse binary string to dict ?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have `flask`-service. Sometimes I can get `json` message without a point at `http` header. In this case I'm trying to parse message from `request.data`. But the string from `request.data` is really hard thing to parse. It's a binary string like this:

```
b'{\n    "begindate": "2016-11-22", \n    "enddate": "2016-11-22", \n    "guids": ["6593062E-9030-B2BC-E63A-25FBB4723ECC", \n              "5A9F8478-6673-428A-8E90-3AC4CD764543", \n              "D8243BA1-0847-48BE-9619-336CB3B3C70C"]\n}'
```

When I'm trying to use `json.loads()`, I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'
```

Function of converting to string (`str()`) doesn't work good too:

```
'b\'{\\n    "begindate": "2016-11-22", \\n    "enddate": "2016-11-22", \\n    "guids": ["6593062E-9030-B2BC-E63A-25FBB4723ECC", \\n              "5A9F8478-6673-428A-8E90-3AC4CD764543", \\n              "D8243BA1-0847-48BE-9619-336CB3B3C70C"]\\n}\''
```

I use `Python 3`. What can I do to parse `request.data` ?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Just `decode` it before passing it to `json.loads`:

```
b = b'{\n    "begindate": "2016-11-22", \n    "enddate": "2016-11-22", \n    "guids": ["6593062E-9030-B2BC-E63A-25FBB4723ECC", \n              "5A9F8478-6673-428A-8E90-3AC4CD764543", \n              "D8243BA1-0847-48BE-9619-336CB3B3C70C"]\n}'
r = json.loads(b.decode())
print(r)
{'begindate': '2016-11-22',
 'enddate': '2016-11-22',
 'guids': ['6593062E-9030-B2BC-E63A-25FBB4723ECC',
  '5A9F8478-6673-428A-8E90-3AC4CD764543',
  'D8243BA1-0847-48BE-9619-336CB3B3C70C']}
```

[Python 3.x](http://www.diveintopython3.net/strings.html#byte-arrays) makes a clear distinction between the types:

- `str` = `'...'` literals = a sequence of Unicode characters (UTF-16 or UTF-32, depending on how Python was compiled)
- `bytes` = `b'...'` literals = a sequence of octets (integers between 0 and 255)

[Link for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269765/what-does-the-b-character-do-in-front-of-a-string-literal)

Comment: You could also write `json.loads(user.body)`, in case that `user.body` is a binary object that represent a python's dictionary.

Comment: you are a diamond mate!