# Get data from JsonResponse in django

Tags: django

I wanted to know how to get data from a JsonResponse in django. I made a JsonResponse that works like this

```
def pfmdetail(rsid):
   snpid = parseSet(rsid)
   if not snpid:
      return HttpResponse(status=404)
   try:
      data = SnpsPfm.objects.values('start', 'strand', 'type', 'scoreref', 'scorealt', 
                    rsid=F('snpid__rsid'), pfm_name=F('pfmid__name')).filter(snpid=snpid[0])
   except SnpsPfm.DoesNotExist:
      return HttpResponse(status=404)
   serializer = SnpsPfmSerializer(data, many=True)
   return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)
```

and then I call directly the method like this

```
def pfmTable(qset,detail):
   source = pfmdetail(detail)
   print(source)
   df = pd.read_json(source)
```

but it gives me an error. I know it's wrong because with the print it returns the status of the response which is 200 so I suppose that the response is fine but how can I access the data inside the response? I tried `import json` to do `json.load` but with no success. I even tried the methods of QueryDict but stil I can't acess to the content I'm interested

P.S. I know that `data` contains something because if i display the jsonresponse on the browser i can see the JSON

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As you can see here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects.

`JsonResponse` object holds json in its `content` attribute.

So to access it try this:

```
df = pd.read_json(source.content)
```

Or to see it printed do:

```
print(source.content)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I searched in the wrong part of the documentation xD

Comment: Not a problem, two most important attributes of the djangos response objects are `status_code` and `content`. But there are more, to get more familiar with them see this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#id2

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't using pandas, then you should process the content attribute of the `JSONResponse` object like this:

`r = json.loads(source.decode())`

I got the answer here: [How to parse binary string to dict ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41606527/how-to-parse-binary-string-to-dict)